# Casting float* to char* while looping over a 2-D array in linear memory on device

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

On Page 21 of the CUDA 4.0 programming guide there is an example (given below) to illustrate looping over the 
elements of a 2D array of floats in device memory. The dimensions of the 2D are **width*height**

```
// Host code
int width = 64, height = 64;
float* devPtr;
size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch,
width * sizeof(float), height);
MyKernel<<<100, 512>>>(devPtr, pitch, width, height);


// Device code
__global__ void MyKernel(float* devPtr, size_t pitch, int width, int height)
{
   for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r) 
    {
       float* row = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
          for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) 
              {
              float element = row[c];
              }
     }
}
```

Why has the `devPtr` device memory pointer been cast to a character pointer  ,char*,  in the **global** kernel function? Can someone explain that line please. It looks a bit weird.

Comment: Just a reminder to accept an answer if it did indeed answer your question.

Answer (score 9):

This is due to the way [pointer arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) works in C. When you add an integer `x` to a pointer `p`, it doesn't always add `x` bytes. It adds `x` times `sizeof(*p)` (the size of the object to which p points).

```
float* row = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
```

By casting `devPtr` to a `char*`, the offset that is applied (`r * pitch*`) is in number of 1-byte increments. (because a `char` is one byte).  Had the cast not been there, the offset applied to devPtr would be `r * pitch` *times 4* bytes, as a `float` is four bytes.

For example, if we have:

```
float* devPtr = 1000;
int r = 4;
```

Now, let's leave out the cast:

```
float* result1 = (devPtr + r);
// result1 = devPtr + (r * sizeof(float)) = 1016;
```

Now, if we include the cast:

```
float* result2 = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r);
// result2 = devPtr + (r * sizeof(char)) = 1004;
```

Answer (score 1):

The cast is just to make the pointer arithmetic work right;

```
(float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
```

moves r*pitch bytes forward while

```
(float*)(devPtr + r * pitch);
```

would move r*pitch floats forward (ie 4 times as many bytes)

Answer (score 0):

`*(devPtr + 1)` will offset the pointer by 4 bytes (`sizeof(float)`) before the `*` dereferences it.
`*((char)devPtr + 1)` will offset the pointer by 1 byte (`sizeof(char)`) before the `*` dereferences it..