# Array pointer to find largest number

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a= malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    scanf("%d %d",a,a+1);
    if(*a<*(a+1))
    {
        *a=*(a+1);
        }
    printf("%d",*a);
    return 0;
}
```

Can I use the same array pointer to input 2 numbers and find largest number among them, as shown in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work, although it might be perceived as more readable to use bracket notation for array elements. You also only need to malloc space for 2 elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    scanf("%d %d", &a[0], &a[1]);
    if(a[0] < a[1])
    {
        a[0] = a[1];
    }
    printf("%d", a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

[Read more about pointers and how they work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598394/4543629)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Because when you say `*a` you are pointing to the 0th location of the array and getting the value there and when you say `*(a+1)` you are pointing to 1st location of the array. Same analogy for `&a` and `&(a+1)`.