# Pointer to an Integer Array and Printing Sum

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

So, I was told to...
"Write a function Adder() that receives a pointer to an integer array as input, and uses this
pointer to return the sum of elements of the array."
And I was pretty successful. My code is

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int Adder (int *ptr)
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        sum=*(ptr+i)+sum;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int array[5]={1,1,1,1,1};
    int sum;
    int *ptr=array;
    Adder(ptr);
    sum=Adder(ptr);
    cout<<sum;
}
```

The thing I can't understand is where I

```
Adder(ptr)
```

and then

```
int Adder (int *ptr)
```

"ptr" holds the address, right? While, " *ptr " holds the actual value. I can't understand how this worked. Can someone please explain?

Comment: `ptr` hols the address while `*ptr` is the value the pointer pointing to. `*` is called dereferencing operator. It dereference the pointer to get the value it points to

Comment: Your question is not clear. what's the thing you are asking about

Comment: also [stop including `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this works is because adding 1 to an `int` pointer (in your case `ptr`) will actually add the size of an `int` (which can vary depending on the machine).

See the answers to this question for a more detailed explanation: [Why a pointer + 1 add 4 actually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598361/why-a-pointer-1-add-4-actually)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```cpp
int Adder (int *ptr)
```

defines a function that takes a pointer to an `int` as its argument. In this context, `*ptr` does not refer to the value `ptr` is pointing to.

The line

```cpp
Adder(ptr);
```

invokes that function, passing the local pointer named `ptr`.