# Why the increment of pointer with type (char **) which returned from malloc() make the address forward 8?

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers

While learning OpenCV, I saw the code of function `cv::alignPtr()`, I'm confused with this piece of code:

```
uchar** adata = alignPtr((uchar**)udata + 1, CV_MALLOC_ALIGN);
```

My question is why `(uchar**)udata + 1` make the `udata` forward 8?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `sizeof(uchar*) = 8` on your machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why a pointer + 1 add 4 actually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598361/why-a-pointer-1-add-4-actually)